# PHP Better way to Replace/Match $1

Tags: php

I am trying to replace `$1, $2, $3` variables in a URL with another URL.
You can copy paste my example below and see my solution.

But I feel like there is a more elegant way with an array mapping type function or a better preg_replace type of thing. I just need a kick in the right direction, can you help?

```
    <?php
    /**
    *  Key = The DESIRED string
    *  Value = The ORIGINAL value
    *
    * Desired Result: project/EXAMPLE/something/OTHER
    */
    $data = array(
        'project/$1/details/$2' => 'newby/EXAMPLE/something/OTHER'
    );

    foreach($data as $desiredString => $findMe)
    {
        /**
        * Turn these URI's into arrays
        */
        $desiredString = explode('/', $desiredString);
        $findMe = explode('/', $findMe);

        /**
        * Store the array position of the match
        */
        $positions = array();
        foreach($desiredString as $key => $value) {
            /**
            * Look for $1, $2, $3, etc..
            */
            if (preg_match('#(\$\d)#', $value)) {
                $positions[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        /**
        * Loop through the positions
        */
        foreach($positions as $key => $value){
            $desiredString[$key] = $findMe[$key];
        }

        /**
        * The final result
        */
        echo implode('/', $desiredString);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need `$1` and `$2` if the number after dollar sign means nothing? Why not use `$` instead?

Comment: PS: you could also replace the value right in `preg_match` `if` block like `$desiredString[$key] = $findMe[$key];` and avoid another foreach loop

Comment: Does the `$data` array have to be kept the same or can we re-imagine that as well? Where does the data come from?

Comment: Sure, that "Desired Result: project/EXAMPLE/something/OTHER" and not "Desired Result: project/EXAMPLE/details/OTHER"?

Comment: You can re-imagine any URL you like, im still reading through the comments :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saying, why don't use an array pattern/replacement in preg_replace? Something like this:

```
<?php
/**
*  Key = The DESIRED string
*  Value = The ORIGINAL value
*
* Desired Result: project/EXAMPLE/something/OTHER
*/
$data = array(
    'project/$1/details/$2' => 'newby/EXAMPLE/details/OTHER'
);
$string = 'project/$1/details/$2';

$pattern[0] = '/\$1/';
$pattern[1] = '/\$2/';
$replacement[0] = 'EXAMPLE';
$replacement[1] = 'OTHER';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

echo $result;
```

I think that it's much easier than what you're looking for. You can see that it works here: http://codepad.org/rCslRmgs

Perhaps there's some reason to keep the array key => value to accomplish the replace?

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, it seems to be the most practical solution. The reason for the Arrays was because I couldn't think outside of the box in this way :)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you are out of luck and the functions you need to solve a problem directly just aren't there. This happens with every language regardless of how many libraries and builtins it has.

We're going to have to write some code. We also need to solve a particular problem. Ultimately, we want our solution to the problem to be just as clean as if we had the ideal functions given to us in the first place. Therefore, whatever code we write, we want most of it to be out of the way, which probably means we want most of the code in a separate function or class. But we don't just want to just throw around arbitrary code because all of our functions and classes should be reusable.

My approach then is to extract a useful general pattern out of the solution, write that as a function, and then rewrite the original solution using that function (which will simplify it). To find that general pattern I made the problem bigger so it might be applicable to more situations.

I ended up making the function `array array_multi_walk(callback $callback [, array $array1 [, array $array2 ... ]])`. This function walks over each array simultaneously and uses `$callback` to select which element to keep.

This is what the solution looks like using this function.

```
$chooser = function($a, $b) {
  return strlen($a) >= 2 && $a[0] == '$' && ctype_digit($a[1])
    ? $b : $a;
};

$data = array(
  'project/$1/details/$2' => 'newby/EXAMPLE/something/OTHER'
);

$explodeSlashes = function($a) { return explode('/', $a); };
$find = array_map($explodeSlashes, array_keys($data));
$replace = array_map($explodeSlashes, array_values($data));

$solution = array_multi_walk(
    function($f, $r) use ($chooser) {
        return array_multi_walk($chooser, $f, $r);
    },
    $find, $replace);
```

And, as desired, `array_multi_walk` can be used for other problems. For example, this sums all elements.

```
$sum = function() {
  return array_sum(func_get_args());
};

var_dump(array_multi_walk($sum, array(1,2,3), array(1,2,3), array(10)));
// prints the array (12, 4, 6)
```

You might want to make some tweaks to `array_multi_walk`. For example, it might be better if the callback takes the elements by array, rather than separate arguments. Maybe there should be option flags to stop when any array runs out of elements, instead of filling nulls.

Here is the implementation of `array_multi_walk` that I came up with.

```
function array_multi_walk($callback)
{
  $arrays = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
  $numArrays = count($arrays);
  if (count($arrays) == 0) return array();
  $result = array();
  for ($i = 0; ; ++$i) {
    $elementsAti = array();
    $allNull = true;
    for ($j = 0; $j < $numArrays; ++$j) {
      $element = array_key_exists($i, $arrays[$j]) ? $arrays[$j][$i] : null;
      $elementsAti[] = $element;
      $allNull = $allNull && $element === null;
    }
    if ($allNull) break;

    $result[] = call_user_func_array($callback, $elementsAti);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

So at the end of the day, we had to write some code, but not only is the solution to the original problem slick, we also gained a generic, reusable piece of code to help us out later.

Comment: You implementation is *much worse* than the original (which is, in fact, takes only 7 lines of meaningful code). It is absolutely unreadable and unmaintainable

Comment: It isn't all about the line count. I'll admit that I prefer a functional style over a procedural one (therefore I'll take my array_maps over a for-loop), but you'll have to explain your opinion more fully. The way I see it, I solved his problem with 4 lines defining a simple, one-statement anonymous callback and 1 additional line to take $data, make the call to `array_multi_walk`, and assign the result. Plus, the  `array_multi_walk` function is fairly general-purpose can be reused.

Comment: the OP's implementation is trivial and easy to read, your - not. I cannot explain better, I just cannot get what your code does at first glance, and I easily can do that looking at the OP's code.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort to think this out, your way seems a bit more complicated. If you look at the Answer I picked you'll see how the person Juan made it very practical and simple -- which in my opinion is always the goal when possible.

Answer (score 2):

Why there should not be $2,$4 but $1,$2 ?if you can change your array then it can be solved in 3 or 4 lines codes.

```
$data = array(
    'project/$2/details/$4' => 'newby/EXAMPLE/something/OTHER'
);

foreach($data as $desiredString => $findMe)
{
    $regexp = "#(".implode(')/(',explode('/',$findMe)).")#i";
    echo preg_replace($regexp,$desiredString,$findMe);
}
```

Comment: You have to be careful if the strings contain meta or escape characters which are interpreted by `preg_*`

Answer (score 1):

I've shortened your code by removing comments for better readability. I'm using `array_map` and the mapping function decides what value to return:

```
<?php

function replaceDollarSigns($desired, $replace)
{
    return preg_match('#(\$\d)#', $desired) ? $replace : $desired;
}

$data = array(
    'project/$1/details/$2' => 'newby/EXAMPLE/something/OTHER',
);

foreach($data as $desiredString => $findMe)
{
    $desiredString = explode('/', $desiredString);
    $findMe = explode('/', $findMe);
    var_dump(implode('/', array_map('replaceDollarSigns', $desiredString, $findMe)));
}
?>
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/qVLmn

You can also omit the function by using `create_function`:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'project/$1/details/$2' => 'newby/EXAMPLE/something/OTHER',
);

foreach($data as $desiredString => $findMe)
{
    $desiredString = explode('/', $desiredString);
    $findMe = explode('/', $findMe);
    $result = array_map(
        create_function(
            '$desired, $replace',
            'return preg_match(\'#(\$\d)#\', $desired) ? $replace : $desired;'
        ),
        $desiredString,
        $findMe);
    var_dump(implode('/', $result));
}
?>
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/OC0Ak

Comment: With PHP 5.3 you can use function literals instead of create_function to make this solution even better. Check 'em out!

Comment: BTW: in my example the decimal after dollar sign isn't important. so you can replace your 'placeholder' by every expression you want when adopting callback function

Comment: Ideone.com shows, that second example is 10ms faster, but here, doing local tests, first one is round about 25% faster

Comment: There's not likely to be a startling difference between the anonymous function and the named function in terms of performance. I believe PHP 5.3's function literals close the disparity even further. (create function, AFAIK, uses trickery with eval and thus has to run the parser again and so forth, so there is some cost there).

Comment: Your first example was pretty good. I think using an anonymous function: array_map(function() {return preg_match ...} would be a nicer way to toss it together (But thats for readability in my opinion) Anyways this was the 2nd best answer :)